# CGRect wrong position when adding UIView

Tags: uiview, addsubview, cgrect

This is my code

```
CGRect testr = CGRectMake(1, 50, 320, 200);
WeatherViewController *tv = [[WeatherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WeatherViewController" bundle:nil];
UIView *testview = [tv.view initWithFrame:testr];
[self.view addSubview:testview];
```

No matter what values i put in my CGRectMake the View still end up at the top of my baseView. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "on top"? you mran its y point is lower than ur base views? or infront of it? maybe if you add an image I will understand.

Comment: Sorry for bad english, i mean that i want the subview to be added with a greater Y value, the view should be closer to "the bottom of the screen".

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you are giving the testView the rect of the viewControllers view which cannot be modified because that is the mainView of that ViewController and will always be the same even if you use the initWithFrame:

So the way you have done it will not work as you want it. You ill have to create a new UIView like this:

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

A UIViewController creates a UIView automatically and cannot be modified.